# How to remove first "=" in all excell cells

Tags: excel

How to remove first "=" in all excell cells. There are cells where phone number has this character. Example: `=1234/567` and this phone number will be calculated.

**Edit**:  `=1234/567` must be converted to `1234/567`

**Edit**: To clear things `abc=123` must not be changed, because = is in a middle of word.

Comment: Wondering...is there a single quote in front of the number? An equal sign would be understood as a formula. How is it formatted?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Phone number is interpeted as a formula. And for `=1234/567` you get 0.01

Comment: There are no single quote in front of the number. Should it be there ?

Comment: If you want to keep the `=` sign in there, you need to add a `'` in front of it in order to tell Excel not to interpretate it as a formula. Otherwise, you can just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the '=' sign in formulas.  If Excel had regex replacements, you could do this (Word does), but I don't think it does.

How about a quick VBA solution?

```
Sub RemoveLeadingEquals()

  Dim r As Range
  For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If Left(r.Formula, 1) = "=" Then
      r.NumberFormat = "@"   '  This *might* not be necessary
      r.Formula = Mid(r.Formula, 2)
    End If
  Next r

End Sub
```

Check if the forced text formatting (commented above) is necessary.  It won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Select all cells contain your numbers
Press CTRL+H
Fill "Find What" input box with "="
Just left blank the "Replace with" input box 
click "Replace All".

Comment: Sorry, That would remove all text after `=`. And not only `=` itself.

Comment: sorry, just remove the *, the correct "Find What" input box value is "="

Comment: Sorry, but my question is how to remove **first** `=` in a cell, and not all `=` characters.

Answer (score 0):

this is so simple you want to remove just = sign 
so 
press CTRL+f
enter = 
Replace with nothing 
that's it